# Youtube Upload within Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, moviepy

Is it possible to upload a video from another running python script using youtube-upload?

I have a script which creates a video in moviepy and would like to upload that created video to youtube.

How can I go about doing this? e.g.

```
from youtube_upload import upload_video
upload_video("1.mp4", "example title")
```

I'm using Python 3 and Windows OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Try the link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video It has a sample python script with the usage guidelines.

Comment: I've tried using that script, however it is written in python 2.

Comment: It's easy to port from py2 to py3. Doesn't require much efforts.

Comment: I've converted it and running it now, however I'm getting the message:  File "upload_video.py", line 77, in get_authenticated_service
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE). Even though I have the client_secrets.json file in the same directory as the script.

Comment: could you paste properly formatted upload_video.py source code ported script along with your question?

Comment: Very strange, I fixed it by moving the script and json file to my desktop from my google drive, not sure what would cause it to behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

pls try this
give it a shot ytb_up based selenium

https://github.com/wanghaisheng/ytb-up
features YOU MAY NEED

1. proxy support

auto detect whether need a proxy
2. cookie support

for those multiple channels under same google account
3. schedule time publish

you can explictly specify a date and time for each video or you can set publish policy and daily public count,for example,daily count is 4,you got 5 videos,then first 4 will be published 1 day after the upload date ,the other 1 will be 2 days after the upload date
4. fix google account verify